# How to position labels in chart so that they don't overlap the chart elements

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

I have Chart `Control value` that show me my network statistics:

```
Series seriesPps;
```

This is my timer tick that show my the statistics

```
private void chartTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
                if (seriesPps.Points.Count() > 300)
                    seriesPps.Points.RemoveAt(0);
                seriesPps.Points.Add(wf.PacketsPerSecond);

                DataPoint _point = default(DataPoint);
                foreach (DataPoint item in chart1.Series[1].Points)
                {
                    item.Label = "";
                    item.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.None;
                }

                chart1.Series[1].LegendText = chart1.Series[1].Name = MyValue + " Packets/s";
                DataPoint Point = chart1.Series[1].Points[chart1.Series[1].Points.Count - 1];
                Point.Label = chart1.Series[1].Name;

                chart1.ResetAutoValues();
}
```

And this is how i want it to be:

[image]

And this is how it's looks like:

[image]

As you can see my label value is under the `Chart` line so i cannot see it.
is it possible to `Align Right` like the first pic ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these from `VB.NET`, they might help but never had this issue so shooting in the dark

```
 chart1.Series[1].SmartLabelStyle.AllowOutsidePlotArea = LabelOutsidePlotAreaStyle.Yes
 chart1.Series[1].SmartLabelStyle.IsMarkerOverlappingAllowed = False
 chart1.Series[1].SmartLabelStyle.MovingDirection = LabelAlignmentStyles.Right
```

Comment: translated in C#                                                                            
            chart1.Series[1].SmartLabelStyle.AllowOutsidePlotArea = LabelOutsidePlotAreaStyle.Yes; 
                    chart1.Series[1].SmartLabelStyle.IsMarkerOverlappingAllowed = true;
                    chart1.Series[1].SmartLabelStyle.MovingDirection = LabelAlignmentStyles.Right;